# Can't read Tag title

Tags: templates, scriban

I can't read tag title in scriban in sitecore while I can reach out the path and the display name correctly

**the code I use to read title:**

```
indTags = i_item.ProductIndustryTags.targets
 {{- for ind in  indTags -}}
    <li>
      <a class="esds-cards__source">{{ind.title}}</a>
    </li>
    {{- end -}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
{{ind.Title}}
```

or

```
{{ind['Title']}}
```

Comment: didn't work , but there's a small hint i noticed when make the field of Title on tag template is shared , the title display correctly , i have no idea why

Comment: Oh, can you check your language version is published?

Comment: Yes it's published , but the issue also occurs on CM not CD only